# on SQL How to call values by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have this SQL Query.

In the query below,
a random one of the data in the insert into the first part will be set today, 
and a random one from the bottom insert into the data tomorrow. 
And this will continue like this. How can I write this query?

```
select * from #tempAccessCode
declare @accessCode int=  ( select accessCode from #tempAccessCode)
declare @prefix int=  ( select prefix from #tempAccessCode)

------------------------------------------------
create table #TempPrefix(AccessCode nvarchar(max),Prefix nvarchar(max))


insert into #TempPrefix values ('1671','6710')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1670','6700')                                   
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1669','6690')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1668','6680')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1667','6670')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1666','6660')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1665','6650')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1664','6640')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1663','6630')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1662','6620')
----------------------------------------------
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1661','6610')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1660','6600') 
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1659','6590')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1658','6580')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1657','6570')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1656','6560')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1655','6550')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1654','6540')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1653','6530')
insert into #TempPrefix values ('1652','6520')

declare @AccessCodee nvarchar(max)
declare @prefixx nvarchar(max)

Select top 1 @prefixx = Prefix,@AccessCodee=AccessCode  from #TempPrefix order by  newid()

Select @prefixx,@AccessCodee

drop table #TempPrefix
-------------------------------------------------

update  [CallList]  set AccessCode = @AccessCodee , Prefix = @prefixx 
where  CampaignId  =5409 and ListId=@listId
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, or what you are trying to do. Also, are you using mysql or sql server? Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I will insert to CallList table accesscode and prefix. And today I will insert today from 6620 to 6710 and tomorrow from 6520 to 6610. And it will keep going like this. How can I do that ? –

Comment: So you're reducing the number by 100 each day? What happens when you get to `20` and `110`? Are the next numbers `-80` and `10`?

Comment: @Larnu you understand me wrong. One of the value in first 10 insert into will set today. One of the value in last 10 insert into will set tomorrow RANDOMLY. And it will going to be like that. How can I do that ?

Comment: Like @HoneyBadger I don't follow. You aren't clear here.  `6520` is 100 less that `6620` and `6610` and `100` less thab `6710`, so why I *assumed* you were reducing by `100` (a logical step). YOu need to explain better, here and show your expected results.

Comment: @Larnu it is not about reducing, I only choose one of them and use it in this query update  [CallList]  set AccessCode = [@]AccessCodee , Prefix = [@]prefixx

Comment: @BatuhanBakar, what you mean by today and tomorrow. Do you update these values for two days at a time or for one day ?

Comment: I don't understand either. What does "And it will keep going like this" mean? Maybe it helps if you show the values for the third day. If this is not about ten and hundred less, then where do you get these values from?

Comment: @VenkataramanR from 6620 to 6710 one of them will insert today randomly. Tomorrow from 6520 to 6610 will insert tomorrow one of them randomly. And it will keep going like this.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner third day will be from 6620 to 6710.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, the daily task is: Insert a random row from a set of rows:

- 1st day set = 6620 to 6710 (set #1)
- 2nd day set = 6520 to 6610 (set #2)
- 3rd day set = 6620 to 6710 (set #1 again)
- 4th day set = 6520 to 6610 (set #2 again)
- etc.

So it is two sets of which you alternately pick a row.

### Once

Create a table containing the rows for each set.

```
create table datasets (setno int, accesscode int, prefix int);

insert into datasets (setno, accesscode, prefix)
values
  (1, 1662, 6620),
  (1, 1663, 6630),
  ...
  (1, 1671, 6710),

  (2, 1652, 6520),
  (2, 1653, 6530),
  ...
  (2, 1661, 6610),
  ;
```

### Daily

Use modulo 2 on the current day to get the set number.

```
insert into CallList (date_created, accesscode, prefix)
select top(1) getdate(), accesscode, prefix
from datasets
where setno = datediff(day, '1900-01-01', getdate()) % 2 + 1
order by newid();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for conditional UPDATE, whether there exists prefix already. If prefix (6620 to 6710) exists, go for different prefix(6520 to 6610).If prefix (6620 to 6710) does not exist, go for same prefix(6620 to 6710).

If you run update statement daily, this way, you will get the data randomly from one list(top list) one day and from second list(bottom list) another day.

```sql
DECLARE @AccessCodee NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @prefixx NVARCHAR(max)

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT Prefix
        FROM [CallList]
        WHERE Prefix BETWEEN 6620
                AND 6710
        )
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @prefixx = Prefix
        ,@AccessCodee = AccessCode
    FROM #TempPrefix
    WHERE Prefix BETWEEN 6620
            AND 6710
    ORDER BY newid()

    UPDATE [CallList]
    SET AccessCode = @AccessCodee
        ,Prefix = @prefixx
    WHERE CampaignId = 5409
        AND ListId = @listId
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @prefixx = Prefix
        ,@AccessCodee = AccessCode
    FROM #TempPrefix
    WHERE Prefix BETWEEN 6520
            AND 6610
    ORDER BY newid()

    UPDATE [CallList]
    SET AccessCode = @AccessCodee
        ,Prefix = @prefixx
    WHERE CampaignId = 5409
        AND ListId = @listId
END
```

Comment: it it answered your question, please mark it as answer. so, it will be helpful for others in future.